# Trackpad Proportional Editing

Tags: proportional-editing

Edit: It was because I was using the Lazy Viewport addon. It wouldn't let me change the size for some reason, but now it's working.

How do I change the area of proportional editing on a trackpad? I've searched it up and it says to use the swipe up and down gesture, but that doesn't work. I don't have an extra mouse anywhere so what can I do? I am on Macbook Air and don't have Page Up and Down keys. And I don't want to have to keep changing the size of the editing in a little menu, it will get really annoying.

Answer (score 2):

While moving part of a mesh in proportional editing, you can see the prompts on the bottom of the screen to increase or decrease the proportional influence:

[image]
[image]

By default these are the *Page Up* and *Page Down* keys.